# Sorting using Subtotals and Data Subtotals

Tags: sorting, microsoft-excel-2011

In sorting using Subtotals via Data Subtotals, is there a way I can get all lines of info to come down NOT just the ones I'm totaling?

The only way I have remedied it is copying it down from the Page 2 view after subtotaling but this is quite tedious as I have over 37k lines of data.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (excel 2010):

1. highlight all data and click "sort" to group similar items together
2. use subtotal
3. collapse the groups
4. highlight the collapsed groups and click "sort" again

Comment: This still isn't giving me the columns of info I need on the Subtotal lines. I need 5 columns of info shown on Subtotal line.